# Problema para seleccionar rango de celdas en VBA Excel 2019

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo la siguiente rutina para crear un archivo plano de mi hoja, se supone que debe tomar las filas que tienen datos pero siempre me toma la totalidad de las filas de la hoja, ¿qué puede estar sucediendo?

```
   Sub CreaTXT()

    Dim NombreArchivo, RutaArchivo, lcDato As String
    Dim obj As FileSystemObject
    Dim tx As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim Ht As Worksheet
    Dim i, j, nFilas, nColumnas, lnFilas As Integer
    
    NombreArchivo = "PlanoFE"
    RutaArchivo = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & NombreArchivo & ".csv"
    
    Set Ht = Worksheets("Datos")
    Set obj = New FileSystemObject
    Set tx = obj.CreateTextFile(RutaArchivo)
    
    nColumnas = Ht.Range("A4", Ht.Range("A4").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
    nFilas = Ht.Range("A5", Ht.Range("A5").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
    'lnFilas = ActiveSheet.Range("A5").End(xlDown).Cells.Count
    
    For i = 1 To nFilas
    
        For j = 1 To nColumnas
            tx.Write Ht.Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            If j < nColumnas Then tx.Write ";"
                
        Next j
                
        tx.WriteLine
    
    Next i
    
    tx.Close
    
    Set obj = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "El archivo se ha generado con exito..."

End Sub
```

Esta parte es la que me debe tomar la totalidad de las filas desde A5 hasta la última con dato pero me toma todo:

```
nFilas = Ht.Range("A5", Ht.Range("A5").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pego el código explicado, además `Option Explicit` sirve para obligarte a declarar todas tus variables, y te he puesto como constante `NombreArchivo` ya que lo pones a mano, así que no es una variable.

```
Option Explicit
Const NombreArchivo As String = "PlanoFE"
Sub CreaTXT()

    Dim i, j, lnFilas As Integer
    
    'Declara las variables cuando las vayas a utilizar
    'Cuando pones: Dim NombreArchivo, RutaArchivo, lcDato As String sólo lcDato es string
    'el resto son Variants implicitos, debes declarar cada objeto con su tipo.
    'En excel nunca utilices Integer, porque su rango es de:  -32,768 a 32,767
    'una hoja de un excel actual tiene más de 1 millón de filas, así que te daría error por desbordamiento.
    Dim RutaArchivo As String: RutaArchivo = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NombreArchivo & ".csv"
    Dim Ht As Worksheet: Set Ht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datos")
    Dim obj As FileSystemObject: Set obj = New FileSystemObject
    Dim tx As Scripting.TextStream: Set tx = obj.CreateTextFile(RutaArchivo)
    
    With Ht
        'De este modo hacemos que la última columna (XDF) de la fila 4 va hacia la izquierda hasta toparse
        'con un valor, y esa será la última columna.
        Dim nColumnas: nColumnas = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'Aquí lo mismo pero con filas, la última fila (1048576) de la columna A sube hasta toparse
        'con un valor, y esa será la última fila.
        Dim nFilas As Long: nFilas = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To nFilas
        For j = 1 To nColumnas
            tx.Write Ht.Cells(i + 1, j)
            If j < nColumnas Then tx.Write ";"
        Next j
        tx.WriteLine
    Next i
    tx.Close
    
    'no necesitas vaciar los objetos, lo hace VBA
    'Set obj = Nothing
    MsgBox "El archivo se ha generado con exito..."

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, voy a analizarla, probrarla y observar si me ayuda. gracias por el detalle en las instrucciones que me serviran a entender mucho mejor el código VBA en Excel.

Comment: @AlejandroGarcía perfecto, si hace lo que necesitas recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta para cerrar el tema.

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en la linea que cuenta el numero de filas, cuando abajo de A5 no hay nada, el conteo se va hasta la ultima fila de la hoja.

```
nFilas = Ht.Range("A5", Ht.Range("A5").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
```

Para evitar eso, hay que hacer el conteo de abajo hacia arriba, para encontrar la la ultima fila con datos en base a la columna que se indique.

Seria de la siguiente manera.

```
nfilas = ht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

La linea para contar las columnas también te puede dar problemas, puedes usar esta otra opción.

```
ncolumnas = ht.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```